# MongoDB nReturned in executionStats

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I am curious to know why MongoDB shows a total number in nReturned (limit + skip)?
For example here in this query I'm skipping 10 records and limiting to 10 records.
Now if I check executionStats then it shows 20 (which is double than required records).
So does MongoDB really returns 20 records?

```
db.getCollection('users').explain("executionStats").aggregate([{$sort: {time: 1}},{$skip: 10}, {$limit:10}])
```

[image: Screenshot of executionsStats.]

Answer (score 0):

It probably confusing. It is actually `how many documents cursor has to access`

> explain.executionStats.nReturned
>
> Number of documents that match the query condition. nReturned corresponds to the n field returned by cursor.explain()

It's like you have totally 5 documents.

1. You skip 1 and limit 2 documents, then nReturned is 2.
2. But when you try skip 1, limit 10 or skip 10, limit 1 -> In both the cases, cursor has to return all the documents, then skipping, limiting applied. Hence nReturned in the later case is total number of documents.